# Magento2 : Admin redirection issue

Tags: magento2

I have installed Magento2 on my WAMP server. And when I tried to access `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/admin/` it's redirecting to `http://localhost/admin/admin/dashboard/` (An invalid URL)?

Comment: can you provide a front url ?

Comment: Check backend-frontname and base-url parametets.

Comment: check your admin url from env.php file it is admin or something other .. it will be in app/etc/evn.php

Comment: I think the base url provided in the core_config_data table is a different one. Please update it with your site url

Answer (score 6):

the file `app/etc/env.php` should start like this.. check your backend frontName :)

```
<?php
return array (
  'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin_xu4zwa'
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your magento installation foldername and value in table core_config_data field "base_url" is not same.

1. In terminal run command: **php bin/magento info:adminuri** , say it shows: **admin_mkp**
2. In database run sql:  **SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE (`scope` LIKE '%_url%' OR `path` LIKE '%_url%' OR `value` LIKE '%_url%') LIMIT 50**
3. Check value of web/unsecure/base_url  say value is: http://127.0.0.1/magentoxyzfoldername/
4. Now your adminurl should be like this: http://127.0.0.1/magentoxyzfoldername/**admin_mkp**

note: magentoxyzfoldername is your magento installation folder name.

Answer (score 1):

We can also check the admin url by using command

```
        $ php bin/magento info:adminuri
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the following

- Check Your admin backend name
- make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled in apache
- Make sure you have installed magento properly if not try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

change the base_url value in table `core_config_data` to `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/` instead of `http://localhost/magento2/`, you can find the record in the table using 
`SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url';`.

Answer (score 0):

change base url from **core_config_data** table and check **frontName** in **app/etc/env.php** file. Hope, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

After installation of Magento2 site into a new location, you need to run all magento commands, after changing url in core_config_data table and changing connection in app/etc/env.php file.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url` in `core_config_data` table with your url like : `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/`

Or you can set this setting from admin side 
**Stores > Configuration > General > Web:**
Base Urls

```
Base URL : http://127.0.0.1/magento2/
```

Base Urls (Secure)

```
Base URL : https://127.0.0.1/magento2/
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope it will works!**

First you can check the file app/etc/env.php and check backend frontName should be 'admin' like below.

```
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
   ...........
   ...........
   ...........
];
```

And then run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

try switch to Developer mode

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `base_url` on database `core_config_data` table
And also check `app/etc/env.php`  `frontName` value.
After that:

```
set module:developer
setup:upgrade
clean cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Mysql and run below mysql query:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` set value = "http://127.0.0.1/magento2/admin/" WHERE path like "%base_url"
```

After run Mysql query you need to run below command in ssh terminal for flush cache or you can direct delete magento root var/cache folder. After that try to open magento admin it would work.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

need to enter host entry for local

**sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

*Add the path to your Magento pub/ directory to the DocumentRoot directive*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2/pub
         ServerName hostname.magento.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**sudo systemctl restart apache2**

Answer (score 0):

The redirected url is correct if it is opening properly

/admin is the default url to open the admin dashboard in Magento